# Menu Style in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, submenu

I posted this question over wordpress.stackexchange.com but they closed it and pointed me to post here.

I am not sure whether it is the right place for such question but I did not find any CSS related section here.

Please see the below image.

[image]

Currently my menus are similar to A but I want it to be like B. I also want to change the color of the separator from Black to Green in sub menu. I want this effect only on the sub menu whether sub menu page is selected or not. How can I do that?

Here is the selected code from my style.css:

```
.menu {
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
    background: url() repeat-x 0 -80px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative; /* Required for positioning of sub-menus */
}
.menu li ul {
    display: none;  /* Required to hide menu when inactive */
    position: absolute;  /* Position the menu below and to the far left */
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
}
/* This is the rule that displays sub-menus when a parent link is clicked */
.menu li.current-menu-parent ul, .menu li.current-menu-item ul {
    display: block;
}
.menu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-right:#3c3c3c solid 1px; 
}
.menu li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    background: url() repeat-x 100% 0;
    padding: 12px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    background-position: 100% -160px;
    color: #fff;
}
/* Styling for current parent item */
.menu li.current-menu-item a, .menu li.current-menu-parent a{
    background: url() repeat-x scroll left bottom #83C839;
}
/* Styling for sub-menus */
.menu li ul {
    width: 805px;
    background: url() repeat-x 0 -120px;
    border: 1px solid #83C839;
    border-style: none none solid;
    border-width: 3px;
}
.menu li ul li {
    padding: 6px 0;
}
.menu li.current-menu-item ul li a, .menu li.current-menu-parent ul li a {
    background: url() repeat-y right center;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 12px 25px;
    margin: -6px 0;
}
    .menu li ul li a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
/* Styling for current page sub-menu links */
.menu li.current-menu-parent ul li.current-menu-item a, .menu li.current-menu-parent ul li.current-menu-item a:hover {
    background: url("") repeat-x scroll left bottom #83C839;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I am using this code in Wordpress Theme. My code is based upon [WordPress Tutorial – Current & Parent Menu Items In Custom Menus](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-tips/wordpress-tutorial-current-parent-menu-items-in-custom-menus/) code, I modified it according to my need.

Comment: Don't see any difference between A & B?

Comment: Could you update a live demo on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: The only difference I'm able to see it's the dot at the end of the submenu, I was able to make this [half-demo](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/QjbuL/) but I need the whole html to make it looks the way you want

Comment: @Jawad! Please see the dot at the end of the submenu.

Comment: @Luis Sánchez! Thanks for the help. You can see the live demo at www.azibl.com. I am using 2 different menu having different styles in my theme.